# freeing a linked_list's nodes, by freeing whole object

Tags: c, memory-management, linked-list

I would to implement the stack using linked-list. Moreover, I want to use something like templates.
Thus I got such structures:

1. node

```
#define node(T)            \
  struct node_##T {        \
    T value;               \
    struct node_##T *next; \
  }
```

2. stack

```
#define stack(T)           \
  struct stack_##T {       \
    size_t size;           \
    node(T) * begin, *end; \
  }
```

At the end I want to free the stack. Always I did it using while/recursive. Somthing like that:

```
while (begin != NULL)
{
    temp = begin;
    begin = begin->next;
    free(temp);
}
```

In my case the usage of this method is more compicated rather than usally. Consequently, I just freeing the object.

```
#include "stack.h"
typedef char* string;
int main() {
  stack(string)* a;
  stack_constructor(string, a);
  stack_resize(a, 5);
  free(a);
  return (0);
}
```

The debug shows that all is fine. I have set two break-points before "free(a)" and after "free(a)".
[before freeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvQXc.png)
[after freeing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyO2k.png)
But I have some doubts about these. I think that we're deleting the memory which we have allocated for the pointer, but the values still in memory. Am I mistakning?

Comment: Why do you use those confusing macros? They make the code look as if it belongs to a different language.

Comment: `free(a)` does not free the `value` member of the node.

Comment: @machine_1 As I comprehend there is two ways (opaque pointers and templates). The templates more safe. We don't use the (void*) cast and memory allocate, where I can get some leaks.

Comment: @Paul Ogilvie  Ok, I see. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`free(a)` frees the object `a` points to. It doesn't free the objects which *that* object points to. So it will free the `stack` object, but it won't free any of the `node` objects.